# How to map data in an array to another array output with different index in Mule Dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have an JSON  like this:

```
{
"invoice-line": [
    {
        "id": "01",
        "date": "2019-06-21",
        "sales-date": "2019-06-21",
        "line-num": "1",
        "item": "Mouse",
        "descrption": "This is line 1 item"
    },
    {
        "id": "02",
        "date": "2019-06-21",
        "sales-date": "2019-06-21",
        "line-num": "2",
        "item": "Keyboard",
        "descrption": "This is line 2 item"
    },
    {
        "id": "03",
        "date": "2019-06-21",
        "sales-date": "2019-06-21",
        "line-num": "3",
        "item": "Monitor",
        "descrption": "This is line 3 item"
    }
]
}
```

From this input JSON we need to extract the data and map into another output JSON  but with a logic: 
when line-num = 1 then map id, date, sales-date, description
then rest or the array will map id, item, descrption 
Which will look like below:

```
{
"row": [
    {
        "id": "01",
        "date": "2019-06-21",
        "sales-date": "2019-06-21",
        "line-num": "1",
        "item": "",
        "descrption": "This is line 1 item"
    },
    {
        "id": "02",
        "date": "",
        "sales-date": "",
        "line-num": "",
        "item": "Mouse",
        "descrption": "This is line 2 item"
    },
    {
        "id": "03",
        "date": "",
        "sales-date": "",
        "line-num": "",
        "item": "Monitor",
        "descrption": "This is line 3 item"
    }
]
}
```

Also is that possible to perform something like mapping array item (first index) to different output array? For example:

```
{
"row": [
    {
        "id": "",
        "date": "2019-06-21",
        "sales-date": "2019-06-21",
        "line-num": "1",
        "item": "",
        "descrption": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "01",
        "date": "",
        "sales-date": "",
        "line-num": "",
        "item": "Keyboard",
        "descrption": "This is line 1 item"
    },
    {
        "id": "02",
        "date": "",
        "sales-date": "",
        "line-num": "",
        "item": "Mouse",
        "descrption": "This is line 2 item"
    },
    {
        "id": "03",
        "date": "",
        "sales-date": "",
        "line-num": "",
        "item": "Monitor",
        "descrption": "This is line 3 item"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you were looking for:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
row: 
    (payload.invoice-line filter ($.line-num == '1') map {
            id: "",
            date: $.date,
            sales-date: $.sales-date,
            line-num: $.line-num,
            item: "",
            descrption: ""
        })
    ++
    (payload.invoice-line map {
            id: $.id,
            date: "",
            sales-date: "",
            line-num: "",
            item: $.item,
            descrption: $.descrption
    })
```

produces:

```
{
    "row": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "date": "2019-06-21",
            "sales-date": "2019-06-21",
            "line-num": "1",
            "item": "",
            "descrption": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "01",
            "date": "",
            "sales-date": "",
            "line-num": "",
            "item": "Mouse",
            "descrption": "This is line 1 item"
        },
        {
            "id": "02",
            "date": "",
            "sales-date": "",
            "line-num": "",
            "item": "Keyboard",
            "descrption": "This is line 2 item"
        },
        {
            "id": "03",
            "date": "",
            "sales-date": "",
            "line-num": "",
            "item": "Monitor",
            "descrption": "This is line 3 item"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thank a lot, but yes, this isn't what i want as the output field (post target) is not controllable from my side so i cant add header or lines on that row array

Comment: No worries. I can get you the expected output tomorrow morning

Comment: Thanks, that's help me a lot...still looking for the method to apply two different logic to map on one array...

Comment: hopefully the new edit is better. If it is, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: this look great. Thanks for the help!